# Show that $\int \frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^n}=\frac{A\sin x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+B\int {dx \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+C\int {dx \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been trying to develop this integral in parts twice, but I can't come up with anything meaningful,

Could you give me some hints on how to develop this exercise?

Prove that

$$\int \frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^n}=\frac{A\sin x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+B\int {dx \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+C\int {dx \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-2}}, \hspace{1cm} (|a|\neq |b|). $$
and determine the coefficients $A,B$ and $C$, if $n$ is a natural number greater than the unit

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 2):

Denote $I_n= \int \frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^n}$ and note that

\begin{align}
&\frac b{\sin x} \left(\frac{\sin^2x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}\right)'\\
=&\ \frac{(n-1)(b^2-a^2)}{(a+b\cos x)^n}+\frac{2a(n-2)}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}
-\frac{n-3}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-2}}\end{align}

Integrate both sides

\begin{align}
&(n-1)(b^2-a^2)I_n + 2a(n-2)I_{n-1} -(n-3)I_{n-2} \\
= &\int \frac b{\sin x} d\left(\frac{\sin^2x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}\right) 
= \frac{b\sin x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}-aI_{n-1} +I_{n-2} 
\end{align}

which leads to

$$I_n = \frac{A\sin x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+BI_{n-1}+CI_{n-2} $$
with

$$A = \frac b{(n-1)(b^2-a^2)},\>\>\>
B = -\frac {(2n-3)a}{(n-1)(b^2-a^2)},\>\>\>
C = \frac {n-2}{(n-1)(b^2-a^2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

By differentiating the equality, we should prove $$\frac{1}{(a+b\cos x)^n}={d\over dx}\frac{A\sin x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+{B \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}+{C \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-2}}, \hspace{1cm}$$ with $|a|\neq |b|$. Also $${d\over dx}\frac{A\sin x}{(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}{={A\cos x(a+b\cos x)^{n-1}+(n-1)Ab\sin^2 x(a+b\cos x)^{n-2}\over (a+b\cos x)^{2n-2}
}
\\=
{A\cos x(a+b\cos x)+(n-1)Ab\sin^2 x\over (a+b\cos x)^{n}}
\\={Aa\cos x+Ab\cos^2 x+(n-1)Ab\sin^2 x\over (a+b\cos x)^{n}}
}$$
The task of finding proper values $A,B,C$ such that $$\frac{1}{(a+b\cos x)^n}-{B \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-1}}-{C \over (a+b\cos x)^{n-2}}={Aa\cos x+Ab\cos^2 x+(n-1)Ab\sin^2 x\over (a+b\cos x)^{n}}$$should be easy.